# How to invalidate a particular key & data for Loading cache taking a key and data as Mono of List of String

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, invalidation, caffeine-cache

I want to invalidate a particular key & data for cache (of type Loading Cache) defined as - Loading Cache<String, Mono<List< String >>> cachemem.
Here we have single key with list of data in cache . And list of data is model class having a field - id which is determined as key for a particular data in list.

I tried using cachemem.invaldate(key) , but it is not invalidating the particular key as it is cache with a common key and mono of list of data . please help me to provide a function which can invalidate a particular key and data from the cache.

Comment: You can use the `asMap().compute` methods for advanced scenarios